# Get Instagram photos by tag, via php

Tags: php, instagram, file-get-contents

i grab data via file_get_contents and then `preg_match` pics, it has works fine for a two years, but now stoped. Insta refuse and loads empty html page. Would u know how to fix it?

```
<?
file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/roofers");
preg_match( "/window._sharedData \=(.+),\"is_canary/im", $str, $matches );
...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram changed their authentication rules and only logged users can access to public photos now. You can use Instagram API instead.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anybody has same quiestino trouble was in other side
i tried to get page from public hosting iP add, which was blocked by instagram

so queries works pretty well, and even so, it can gives you json_feed from this GET

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/NEEDED_HASHTAG/?__a=1
```

without any parse :-)